stab(x) when the Symmetric group acts on the set of order k-tuples
Question: let $G=S_n$ (the symmetric group of degree $n$) and let $X$ be the set of ordered k-tuples $(x_1,…x_k)$ where $x_i \in \{1,2,…,n\}$ (where $n\ge k \ge 1$).
G acts on X defined by $\sigma(x_1,…,x_k)=(\sigma(x_1),…,\sigma(x_k))$
Determine $orb(x)$ and $stab(x)$ where $x=(1,…,k) \in X$ (then verify the orbit-stabiliser theorem holds).
My thoughts:
$orb(x) = \{(x_1,x_2,…,x_k): x_i \in \{1,2,…,n\}\}$
so $\|orb(x)\| = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$
The stabiliser would be the elements of G which only permute $k<x\le n$, so $\|stab(x)\| = (n-k)!$. The orbit stabiliser theorem obviously applies. I’m not sure how to write the stabiliser using mathemical notation (or if I’m even right).

Looking at what you wrote in your thoughts, it looks like everything is good: The orbit (which may be denoted Orb${G}(x)$, Orb$(x)$, or -- more commonly -- $O_x$) will include all ordered $k$-tuples, of which there are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$. The stabilizer (which I tend to notate Stab${G}(x)$, though is also denoted $G_x$) will include all permutations which include none of the elements contained in the chosen $k$-tuple $x$. I hope this answers your question?

(aI You obviously mean the right thing when you write $orb(x)$ but you need to annotate it by adding in the set builder the conditions "$x_i\ne x_j$". (ii) I personally would write the stabilizer as $S_{{1}} \times S_{{2}}\times \dots\times S_{{k}}\times S_{{k+1,k+2,\dots,n}}$.

Call "$*$" the induced natural action
of $S_n$ on the cartesian product of $k$ copies of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. By definitions of $*$-stabilizer and equality between ordered $k$-tuples:
$$\operatorname{Stab}_*((1,\dots,k))=\bigcap_{i=1}^k\operatorname{Stab}(i)$$
and hence:
$$\left|\operatorname{Stab}_*((1,\dots,k))\right|=(n-k)!$$
On the other hand, from the definition:
$$\operatorname{Orb}_*((1,2,\dots,k))=\{(\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\dots, \sigma(k)),\sigma\in S_n\}$$
follows that:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\left|\operatorname{Orb}_*((1,2,\dots,k))\right| &= n(n-1)\dots(n-(k-1)) \\
&=n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1) \\
&= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
\end{alignat}
So indeed:
$$\left|\operatorname{Orb}_*((1,2,\dots,k))\right|\cdot\left|\operatorname{Stab}_*((1,\dots,k))\right|=|S_n|$$
